# thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory to Google Apps

Tags: active-directory, google-apps

I've set everyones photo within Active Directory to the attribute `thumbnailPhoto`. How do I sync this to their Google Profile? I'm currently using GADS but can't find any instructions to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script is working for me.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties thumbnailphoto, EmailAddress | where {$_.thumbnailphoto} | foreach {$_.thumbnailphoto | Set-Content -Path "C:\Downloads\ADPicture\Pictures\$($_.EmailAddress).jpg" -Encoding Byte}


C:\gam\gam.exe all users update photo C:\Downloads\ADPicture\Pictures\#user#.jpg
```

Comment: Can't wait to try this.

Comment: Make sure to edit the directories in my script to reflect file locations of your server and to install GAM properly.

Answer (score 1):

GAM can set a profile photo:
https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#user-profile-photos

you'd need to write a script that extracted the AD photo for a user to a file and then uploaded it to Google via a GAM command.

Jay